# Why Finsler Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, finsler-geometry

Why do we need to generalize Riemannian geometry to Finsler geometry? What is the main reason behind it? we generalized the Differential manifold to the Riemannian manifold because we required differentiation. In Finsler we have direction and many volume forms say Busemann-Hausdorff, Holmes-Thomson, and others but what are they used for? Can anyone please answer me or suggest some book or article where I can find a satisfactory explanation for these questions? I am a beginner in this field so sorry if this is a very silly question.